# Is ObjectOutputStream.writeObject to a file thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, serialization, concurrency, objectoutputstream

I am working on an application that has to serialize objects to a file for use later. There are multiple threads calling method `writeObject` (for different objects, same file) concurrently. Is the method thread-safe? Do I have to synchronize the write operation in application code?

For example: Thread 1 serializes object A, Thread 2 serializes object B. If I didn't synchronize them, would A and B get mixed up with each other in the file? Thanks!

Comment: even if this method is thread-safe, the objects will be written to the file in random order. Are you ok with this?

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov Yes, the order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, Java Serialization [is dangerous](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/seccodeguide-139067.html#8) so it should be avoided.

No, `ObjectOutputStream` is not *thread-safe*. The API doesn't seem to make any claim about that. You can also check the source code, where there is only thread-safety for security.

It's not *thread-hostile* so you can write to two independent `ObjectOutputStream`s concurrently.

`OutputStream`s from `java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream​` are *thread-safe* but that is not automatically conferred to "decorators".

`Writer`s have some explicit locking, but makes an absolute pigs ear of it.

Comment: *Java Serialization is dangerous*... What is a better alternative?

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If they are writing to the same file, then yes, this should be synchronized. But this is generally true even outside of object serialization: If you have two or more threads writing to the same stream, they need to be synchronized.

If they are each writing to their own streams/files, then you don't have resource conflict and it would be thread-safe

Comment: If you have two or more threads writing to the **same stream**, synchronizing won't help with your design flaw.

Comment: @Kayaman I am using (at least trying to use) the term *synchronizing* more abstractly than its keyword Java definition. For instance, using a queue with just one writer thread to synchronize.

Comment: Alright then. It wasn't immediately clear and might give the impression that streams are a similarly sharable resource as let's say a collection, as long as it's thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

If multiple threads are writing to same file you have to synchronize the writing method as `ObjectOutputStream` is not threadsafe  out of the box. You might end up with mixedup result and different kind of threading issues.